# HTML not linking scripts or stylesheets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to link jquery and a css file to some HTML and I'm having no luck. The CSS for the page is not styling anything in my browser (Chrome). Also, I've tried putting the script tags in the body and the head (I know this is bad style, I just wanted to try) and I've got console.log()s in my script that aren't logging anything so I know they aren't being linked properly. Can anyone tell me why this isn't behaving?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="WLE.css">
        <title>w/Way Less Effort</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="logo" src="WLE.jpg">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("pre-fade");
            $(document).ready(function() {
                console.log("fading out");
                $("#logo").fadeOut("slow");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine.Can you put up a fiddle to demonstrate the `not working`

Comment: is this correct filename? `WLE.css`

Answer (score 0):

Replace script with this, abouve body tag :P css link is good but maybe css not work or name is not like u writed.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Ist work");
    </script>
```

But and this work if i see good. http://jsfiddle.net/2Fv8f/

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct
your file css should nam " WLE.css " i mean with capital letters and should be in the same directory with this html file
.
for JQuery it's linked correctly and its work for me and the Img fade out in my test .
and for test your linked files (images , css , js ) you can do that with any code you write . go to your page in Chrome and :

`Click right > Inspecte element > Network (Tab)` :

and Refresh the page if any images or files doesn't link correctly it will show in red color .
try and you will see .
I hope that's will help you .